signals с массивами в solidjs - почему не работет?
signals в solidjs с массивами; не могу понять почему это не работает вроде text_items() изменяются, но в итоге setText_items() просто не работает и дальше по программе соответственно отваливается вся реактивность
text_items().forEach((item, index) => {
  invoke<string>("translate_from_en_to_ru", { word: item.en }).then((res) => {
    console.log("res = " + res + ", index: " + index)
    item.ru = res
  });
})

const word_list = text_items();

setText_items([...word_list]);
console.log(word_list)


Прежде чем опубликовать ваш вопрос, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
